# load different .qrc file based on screen size

Tags: qt

Correct me if i'm wrong but my understanding is all .qrc files that were added to the qt program are loaded into ram when the app runs. Is it possible to load the .qrc files dynamically into ram? For example I have 3 image files one for 720p, one for 1080p, and one for 4k. What I have in my main.cpp is code to get the screen resolution and loads an image from the .qrc. I do not want to put the images onto the local filesystem because of speed and also it is accessible by anyone.

Is there another option to store images files as one file that is loaded into ram based on screen size?

Answer (score 4):

documentation [states](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qresource.html#details)

> Dynamic Resource Loading
>
> A resource can be left out of an application's binary and loaded when it is needed at run-time by using the registerResource() function. The resource file passed into registerResource() must be a binary resource as created by rcc.